# Modifying an example in CGAL

Tags: cgal

How can i modify this example to load a point soup from a mesh and repair it ?
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/Polygon_mesh_processing_2repair_polygon_soup_example_8cpp-example.html

I did try using other examples loading meshes. But the structures for points and polygon are different and i am not able to read meshes using them.

Answer (score 0):

You can load polygon soups using `CGAL::IO::read_polygon_soup(points, polygons)`.

See for example this example: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/Polygon_mesh_processing_2orient_polygon_soup_example_8cpp-example.html.

```cpp
int main(int, char**)
{
  [...]
  std::vector<K::Point_3> points;
  std::vector<std::vector<std::size_t> > polygons;
  if(!CGAL::IO::read_polygon_soup(filename, points, polygons) || points.empty())
  {
    std::cerr << "Cannot open file " << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  [...]
  CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::repair_polygon_soup(points, polygons);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. I tried that but when i added this line : PMP::repair_polygon_soup(points, polygons, CGAL::parameters::geom_traits(Array_traits())); i got some errors regarding other classes. "Error C2664 'bool Array_traits::Equal_3::operator ()(const Custom_point &,const Custom_point &) const': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'const Custom_point &'"

Comment: the part with `Array_traits` is because this specific example uses custom point types. In general you will just be using a standard point type defined by a standard kernel, and you will not have to use this extra parameter. If you are still unsure what to do, please post the code somewhere (a github gist for example).